# JPQL can not find a foreign key

Tags: jpql

Just a quick question. Want to join two tables A and B, where a_fk is A's table foreign key and b_pr is B's primary key. Relation between A and B is one-to-one bidirectional. 
A and B are corresponding to A and B table Entity classes.
I have jpql query `"select b from A a, B b where a.a_fk=b.b_pr";` Eclipse fails to compile saying that column a_fk does not exist. 
I have created a Native sql query and checked the same sql statement, but of course I have translated it to proper sql. And this works.

Question: JPQL does not support foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL uses entities and association between entties. It doesn't use tables, column and foreign keys.

If you want to select all As which have a B, the query is

```
select a from A a inner join a.b
```

If you want to select all As with their B

```
select a from A a left join fetch a.b
```

Read a book about JPA, because you haven't grasped basic concepts about JPA.

Comment: I don't have any book to advise. The Hibernate documentation is very readable, though. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/